# Simulate mouse click on Youtube videos on Android Kitkat

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, youtube

Youtube allows embedding user created playlist with the help of iframe code. I would like to embed them in a webpage to be played back on Android (Kitkat 4.4) tv box hardware. However it requires user to first click on the video.

As I found out that Apple iOS and Android disables autoplay on most mobile platforms to avoid poor user experiences

However, is it possible to simulate a user click on the iframe using Jquery or pure JS solution (preferred). Something like this:

```
 function myFunction() {
         setTimeout(function() {           ("#myiframe").triggerHandler('click');    },3000)
                };
```

I'd be very grateful if somebody can help me with this as this functionality is crucial for my purpose and I have searched extensively but couldn't get a proper solution.

thanks
dkj

Comment: This is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript

Comment: I think this soln can be useable to simulate mouse click however would require a skilled JS dev (which I'm not) to automate user click http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/08/21/triggering-a-youtube-video-from-clicking-a-button-image-and-replacing-when-ended/#comment-10255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning dkjain,

as far as I've read in the [Youtube Player API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Examples), there are several events triggered as soon as the Player is loaded, one of these events that should be used is the `onReady()` event.

Here's some updated code on how to auto-play a single video or a playlist:

HTML:

`<div id="player"/>`
will be the placeholder for the Youtube player

---

**Playing a playlist (with [`playerVars`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#Parameters)):**

JS:

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        playerVars: { 
            'listType': 'playlist',
            'list': 'PLi5VEqNXXQjVJ4-xZb92wTUawkSQRal0u'            
        },
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;

// as soon as the player is loaded, start the playback
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
document.head.appendChild(tag);
```

There is also an `autoPlay: 1` playerVar, but this does not seem to be available on mobile plaforms: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations

---

**Play a single video**

JS:

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'nhX4rQ79C1A',
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;

// as soon as the player is loaded, start the playback
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
document.head.appendChild(tag);
```

JSFiddles showing the above code:

Single video: http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/akjpmvpf/

Playlist: http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/akjpmvpf/4/ (updated again)

Let me know if we are going in the right direction :-)

Comment: Hy very good morning, good to see  your reply, I've been struggling for past 2 days with this. The code works flawlessly for single video however I'm trying to embed a playlist. Could you plz try and make this work for a playlist? Here is my playlist code: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLi5VEqNXXQjVJ4-xZb92wTUawkSQRal0u" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>...thanxs.

Comment: Would this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313216/example-youtube-playlist-code . I tried it but I couldn't get it work.

Comment: Could you take another look? The answer now contains an example of how to play a playlist, the only thing you basically need to change compared to the previous example is to include the `playerVars` instead of giving a VideoID. HTH and happy Easter!

Comment: Hy, 'autoplay': 1, works in desktop browser but will not work my mobile device and that is the problem i've been struggling with.

Comment: Yes, just read about that. I combined the first and second code and now it should work.

Comment: Ah. got it working by just replacing videoid with playlist code. And so once again the day was saved. A simple masterstroke does the trick. I feel so timid.Hahahaha. Any suggestion for a good JS book for beginners ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74510/discussion-between-dkjain-and-sascham78).

Comment: Hi SaschaM78, How's U? Can u plz help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544644/jquery-div-slideshow-hiding-child-elements...thanks dkj