# Jquery div slideshow hiding child elements

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

I am trying to follow Jquery code for a div slideshow. Basically, I want to show `div1` while hiding `div2` (and vice-versa) with all the child elements of the visible `div` to be visible as well.

The code below only show the first child elements of the visible div 
and hides all child elements and then show the child elements while hiding 
the former.

Can someone please help figure out how to show a `div` and its child elements, while hiding the other sibling `div`s? Like a slideshow.

Moreover, it would be great to show only those container `div`s in the slideshow where at least one image element has a src URL set (i.e. not set to null or "").

Thanks
dkj

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow" class="site-content" role="main">
            <div id="div1_wrapper" class="slides">
                <div id="div1_bg">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_option('div1_bg'); ?>" />
                </div>

                <div id="div1_productimg">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_option('div1_productimg'); ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div id="div2_wrapper" class="slides">
                <div id="div2_bg">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_option('div2_bg'); ?>" />
                </div>

                <div id="div2_productimg">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_option('div2_productimg'); ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
   $(function () {
       $('.slideshow div').hide(); // hide all slides
             $('.slideshow div:first-child').show(); // show first slide
                setInterval(function () {
                   $('.slideshow div:first-child').fadeOut(500)
                        .next('div').fadeIn(1000)
                        .end().appendTo('.slideshow');
                },
        3000); // slide duration
     });    
</script>
```

Comment: Could you create us a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Have you looked at any external jquery plugins to achieve this?

Comment: @dkjain I am not very clear with your Question, still giving you a simple approach. Have a look to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments to my previous answer, here's another version that should be closer to your requirement:

1. Remove all wrappers without ANY proper image in it (and I also removed those images from valid wrappers that don't have a source given to avoid "missing image" images)
2. Hide all wrappers and show only the first one
3. Cycle all wrappers, hiding/showing the entire wrapper's content

---

***New Code***

**HTML Code** (unaltered structure, 2 divs and some `src` tags with empty content added):

```
<div id="slideshow" class="site-content" role="main">
    <div id="div1_wrapper" class="slides">
        <div id="div1_bg">
            <img src="<?php echo get_option('div1_bg'); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div id="div1_productimg">
            <img src="<?php echo get_option('div1_productimg'); ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2_wrapper" class="slides">
        <div id="div2_bg">
            <img src="" alt="2 empty pics" />
        </div>
        <div id="div2_productimg">
            <img src="" alt="2 empty pics" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div3_wrapper" class="slides">
        <div id="div3_bg">
            <img src="<?php echo get_option('div3_bg'); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div id="div3_productimg">
            <img src="<?php echo get_option('div3_productimg'); ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div4_wrapper" class="slides">
        <div id="div4_bg">
            <img src="" alt="1 empty pic" />
        </div>
        <div id="div4_productimg">
            <img src="<?php echo get_option('div4_productimg'); ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$().ready(function() {
   var wrappers= $('.slides');
    for(var i=0;i<wrappers.length;i++) {
        if($(wrappers[i]).find('img[src!=""]').length == 0) {            
            // remove wrappers that do not contain any image with source
            $(wrappers[i]).remove();
        } else {            
            // wrapper should not be removed, but remove all images without any source
            $(wrappers[i]).find('img[src=""]').remove();
        }
    }
    // create the slide show and reload the slides, this time only the ones with proper images
    window.slideShow= {};
    slideShow.slides= $('.slides');
    slideShow.numSlides= slideShow.slides.length;
    slideShow.activeSlide= 0;
    slideShow.slides.hide();
    $(slideShow.slides[0]).show();

    window.setInterval(function() {
        $(slideShow.slides[slideShow.activeSlide]).hide('fadein');
        slideShow.activeSlide= slideShow.activeSlide+1 == slideShow.numSlides ? 0 : slideShow.activeSlide+1;
        $(slideShow.slides[slideShow.activeSlide]).show('fadein');
    }, 3000);
});
```

And [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/vpyx1zj1/) to show the changed functionality.

Comment: That worked. Thanks once again, I wish I had sort of JS skills you have, so that I could help other users like me and earn as much appreciation I have for your skills...FANTASTICCC!!!.

Comment: dkjain, it's just a matter of time and practice and you'll get the skills in the end ;-) Glad we found a solution! Do you also want a pause and resume function for the script?

Comment: Yeah, from experience I have learned that perseverance is important in developing a programming knack more than anything else. What do you think ?

Comment: Currently the script is meant to run in non-user interaction environment so resume and pause is not required (though would be good to have in future) however if the script has ability to let user know valid wrapper div (valid slides) that would show in slideshow, that would be helpful. For e.g. Out of 5 wrappers only 3 are valid slides, invalid slides being those wrappers with no images (all image src being empty).

Comment: Hi SaschaM78,  can u plz update the script to have a left & right navigation arrows shown only on mouse hover..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you see, i have some different hacks to solve, you have your own.

Have a look, if it helps you.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gvz1y99g/2/)

```js
$("#div2_wrapper").fadeOut(0);

$(document).ready(function(){
  
 var divslider = 1;
 function jsslider()
 {    
  if(divslider == 1)
  {
   $("#div1_wrapper").fadeOut(500);
   $("#div2_wrapper").fadeIn(400);
   divslider = 2;
   return;
  }
  if(divslider == 2)
  {
   $("#div2_wrapper").fadeOut(500);
   $("#div1_wrapper").fadeIn(400);
   divslider = 1;
   return;
  }
 }

 var interval = setInterval(jsslider, 3000);
    
});
```

```css
#div1_wrapper, #div2_wrapper
{
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
}
 #div2_wrapper
{
    border:3px solid green;
}

/* Borders in CSS are just to see where your div goes. REMOVE IT */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow" class="site-content" role="main">
            <div id="div1_wrapper" class="slides">
                <div id="div1_bg">
                    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
                </div>

                <div id="div1_productimg">
                    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div id="div2_wrapper" class="slides">
                <div id="div2_bg">
                    <img src="http://www.socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png" />
                </div>

                <div id="div2_productimg">
                    <img src="http://www.socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png" />
                </div>
            </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated the Fiddle to better match your question: first remove all slider elements that contain images with no big or product images; then check if at least one element remains. If at least one element has been found, hide all sliders, show the first, initialise the slide show and start cycling the slides.

JS code:

```
$().ready(function() {

    // remove all elements without a source ...
    // .... and hide all slide containers
    $('img[src=""]').parent('div').remove();
    $('.slides').hide();

    window.slideShow= {};

    slideShow.slides= $('.slides .slider-image');
    if (slideShow.slides.length > 0) {

        // unhide all slides that contain at least one image
        for (var i=0;i<slideShow.slides.length;i++) {
           $(slideShow.slides[i]).parent('div').parent('div').show();  
        }

        // on initialisation, hide all image slides and show the first element only
        slideShow.slides.hide();

        $(slideShow.slides[0]).show();
        // show the first parent container
        $(slideShow.slides[0]).parent('div').parent('div').show('fadein');

        // initialise the slideshow properties
        slideShow.activeSlide= 0;
        slideShow.numSlides= slideShow.slides.length;        

        // start the show
        window.setInterval(function() {

            slideShow.nextSlide= slideShow.activeSlide+1 == slideShow.numSlides ? 0 : slideShow.activeSlide+1;

            // hide the element shown before
            $(slideShow.slides[slideShow.activeSlide]).hide('fadein');

            // increase the slide counter by 1; start with 0 if end reached
            slideShow.activeSlide= slideShow.nextSlide;
            // show the new image
            $(slideShow.slides[slideShow.activeSlide]).show('fadein');           
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="site-content" role="main">
        <div id="div1_wrapper" class="slides" style="border: 3px solid red;">
            <div id="div1_bg">
                <img class="slider-image" src="" alt="This has no source assigned" />
            </div>

            <div id="div1_productimg">
                <img class="slider-image" alt="Product Image" src="<?php echo get_option('div1_productimg'); ?>" />
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div id="div2_wrapper" class="slides" style="border: 3px solid green;">
            <div id="div2_bg">
                <img class="slider-image" alt="Big Image" src="<?php echo get_option('div2_bg'); ?>" />
            </div>

            <div id="div2_productimg">
                <img class="slider-image" alt="Product Image" src="<?php echo get_option('div2_productimg'); ?>" />
            </div>
        </div>  

            <!-- more product slides in the demo below... -->
        </div>
```

[4. updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/e7b6nbq3/6/)

This will remove all DIVs with empty images, hide all wrappers and unhide those with at least an image with proper source. It will then cycle the images and hide/unhide the current image slide.

*Remark:* I wouldn't use too many IDs if they are not needed, rather set IDs on elements that require it for identification and using classes for all elements with same function or type (i.e. `<div class="div_big">` rather than `<div id="div1_bg">`)

Comment: Hi, toggling elements seems a gr8 idea but unfortunately it isn't jsut working for me. div1_bg does not show and div1_productimg shows up with div2_wrapper and it child elements. Could be a issue with my CSS but I'm not sure however script by user: divy3993 script is working fine though it's less dynamic and would be repeated code if there were more than 2 wrappers. Also it would be great to take into account to show only those wrapper div's where at least one image element has a src URL set or not set to null or "".

Comment: dkj, I updated the fiddle and code to show the big/product image as some kind of slide show while unhiding the element the currently shown image is a part of. Hope that fits better?

Comment: Ok gr8, the above works except that it completely removes the wrapper div if atleast one of the img src in the wrapper is empty, it should only remove the wrapper div from the slideshow if all of the image elements src's in the wrapper are empty or not set.

Comment: Dear Sascha, "bg" here refers to background (not big) image which is absolutely positioned (with lower z-index and covering whole parent wrapper div) below abs. positioned product image (higher z-index). I kept it that way so I can update it via wordpress's get_option() func. rather than having to update the product element's background css property (in css file via php "style.css.php"). With the updated demo what is happening is that for a wrapper div it's showing the bg_image then fading it out and then fading-in the product image whereas it should be fading-in and out the wrappers cont..

Comment: ...not individual elements, background and product images  within the wrapper div. Hope that make sense..else I will try explaining with an image...

Comment: You don't need IDs for that purpose, simply set `position:relative;` for the wrapper and `position:absolute;` for the background image. OK, before I rewrite the code, what you want is: 1.) Remove all wrappers without images, 2.) collapse (instead of hiding) all wrappers and 3.) show the wrapper's content sequentially? Can I rewrite your HTML code or is it required to maintain the structure?

Comment: You're right about ID's and henceforth I would be careful with using ID's but here the current HTML structure is required. What is want is  1) remove all wrapper without ANY image (even if there is atleast one it should show), 2) Which ever u think is better collapse/hiding should be fine 3) The wrappers not content should be shown sequentially for e.g. SLIDE-1: fadein (Wrapper1 [bgimage + productimg]) fadeout. SLIDE-2 fadein (Wrapper2 [bgimage + productimg]) fadeout...so on...Hope that is more clear...